# Bash : Search and replace value of a variable inside a file

Tags: bash, grep, sh

I have a `input-file` for a code, which has a parameter called `var1`. I need to run a bash script to read and change `var1` inside the `input-file` and submit to the code.

Inside the `input-file`:

```
...
var1=10
...
```

I can use `grep` to get value of `var1`. But how to replace and write `var1` inside the `input-file`?

---

Command I use to obtain `var1`

```
INPUT=input-file
var1=`grep "^var1" $INPUT | awk '{print $3}' | sed "s/'//g"`
```

Comment: Is there any other content in the input-file than the `var1=xxx`?

Comment: The line `$INPUT=input-file` will not work (remove the `$`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

grep doesn't do any substitution. You could consider using sed or awk ... For example:

```
sed  -i 's/\(^var1=\).*/\1Newvalue/' $INPUT
```

will change the value to `Newvalue`

Comment: `Newvalue` is literally substituted here. There is variable `i` I want to use, it simply prints string "i" inside file. I tried `$i`. Still it prints "$i" literally the string. How to print the value?

Comment: @SathishKrishnan use double quotes then.  `sed  -i "s/\(^var1=\).*/\1$i/"`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sed  -i -e 's/\(^var1=\).*/\1Newvalue/' $INPUT
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!